# corosync active-active with 2 virtual IPs - clone constraints task

Tags: high-availability, failovercluster, corosync

I have DNS roundrobin on 2 virtual IP in front of *service*. (Among others the *service* tested was: apache, nginx, varnish, postfix, … It really does not matter. Let's call it just *service*.)

I have corosync config where on two nodes *service* is running (as a clone with `max=2 max-node=1`) and each node has one of 2 virtual IP.

- In case of node failure: Corosync stop, standby mode - other node takes over IP.
- In case of stopping *service*: Cluster brings it up.

But:

- In case of destroying config of the *service*: Cluster cannot start it and it remains stopped/errored but the virtual IP remains.

When the cluster was active/passive there waw no clone.  Primitive *service* was in group with IP and in case of failure also virt IP wasn't started.

I cannot group clone.

How do I solve this?

Please note that it seems to have nothing with ordering, which works just fine.

Comment: Bedazzled by your use of bold. I'll just... be going now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added to `Primitive` option to 'op start': `on-fail="standby"`. Now when my service (the only primitive in clone) cannot start due to faulty config - the node looses also virtIP.
This way I end with migrated resources to healthy node.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the Pacemaker cluster project: http://clusterlabs.org

It can monitor/run/move services across the cluster.

Comment: it was a shortcut, it is pacemaker indeed, it's monitoring, starting etc. - but not in all conditions